# Rollup EMFILE: too many open files, with material-ui icons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, rollup, rollupjs

I have a design system that is built on top of Material-ui version 5. I use rollup as my bundler.

In one of of the custom components, I import an icon from Mui5 `import { Search } from "@material-ui/icons"`

When I build using rollup I get the following error which I'm unsure how to fix:

```
!] Error: Could not load E:\project\node_modules\@material-ui\icons\esm\TransitEnterexitSharp.js 
(imported by node_modules\@material-ui\icons\esm\index.js): EMFILE: too many open files, open 'E:\project\node_modules\@material-ui\icons\esm\TransitEnterexitSharp.js'
```

What config am I missing from rollup? It has the following config:

```js
export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: "esm",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    babel({
      plugins: 
      [
        // comes from https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-2
        [
          'babel-plugin-import',
          {
            'libraryName': '@material-ui/core',
            'libraryDirectory': 'esm',
            'camel2DashComponentName': false
          },
          'core'
        ],
        [
          'babel-plugin-import',
          {
            'libraryName': '@material-ui/icons',
            'libraryDirectory': 'esm',
            'camel2DashComponentName': false
          },
          'icons'
        ]
      ],
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      runtimeHelpers: true
    }),
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
    svgr(),
    image(),
    copy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: "package.json",
          dest: "dist"
        }
      ]
    })
  ]
};
```

I have also tried playing with [umidbekk/babel-plugin-direct-import](https://github.com/umidbekk/babel-plugin-direct-import) but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was fixed in Rollup [v2.53.0](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/releases/tag/v2.53.0) that referenced my exact issue https://github.com/rollup/rollup/pull/4170#issue-684709217